# Web Api calls return 404 on Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, asp.net-web-api

I'm aware this has been asked a lot of times on this site and others, but no solution i've seen so far is working, so here I am.

I have some web api routes set up in an mvc 4 project. Here's a sample:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(name: null, routeTemplate: "Client/Accounts/Save", defaults: new { controller = "AccountsApi", action = "SaveAccount" });
```

Corresponding to the following controller and action:

```
public class AccountsApiController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public object SaveAccount([FromBody] Account input)
    {
      .....
```

This works when running in the built in VS web server, and on a local (windows 7) installation of IIS7.5, with no fancy stuff done to it, but gives a 404 when running in IIS7 on Server 2008 R2.

Info:

- MVC4 is installed on the server
- The application is in an app pool with integrated mode and framework v4

What i've tried:

- Played with routes enough to know it's not a routing issue
- Have `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />` set (is the default anyway)
- Looked at [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2011/05/28/resolve-404-in-iis-express-for-put-and-delete-verbs.aspx)
- Done the aspnet_regiis -ir dance
- Custom errors off, compilation debug=false - if those make any difference.
- There are only custom api routes, no catch all.
- IIS Logs just indicate a 404, as you'd expect; nothing in system event logs

The api uses only `GET` and `POST` requests, neither of which are working. Might also be worth mentioning that the calls are all made via ajax.

`system.web`, `system.webServer`,`runtime` sections from config:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Any suggestions hugely appreciated. Thanks.

**Update**

I reimplemented one of my controllers to use only `HttpResponseMessage` and `HttpRequestMessage`

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetAccount(HttpRequestMessage message)
{
    message.CreateResponse(....
```

and again this works as expected when running locally (both cassini and full IIS local install on Win7), but fails when pushed onto the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasn't able to fix this issue. Almost certainly down to some obscure thing not installed or switched on on the server. Very frustrating as other Web Apis are already working on the same box.

Couldn't spend any more time on it, so just reimplemented using [Service Stack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack) instead, which just works.

Comment: Hey! Did you just give up? I have a problem similar to yours. All actions work but those with PUT and DELETE methods. I tried all the solutions as you did. But giving up is not an option for me.

Comment: Yeah I did give up and reimplement with Service Stack - which is something i'm more familiar and happy with. If put and delete aren't working, it could be firewall related, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828790/restful-put-and-delete-and-firewalls

Comment: No, it didn't work even on the local machine. What drove me mad is that the same application works on IIS Express. I uninstalled IIS then reinstalled it, and recreated the web application and it worked! Maybe my configurations were messed up. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Update:  I just noticed that you said GET methods were not working either, in which case this advice is probably no use to you.

Try changing the signature of the method to

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage SaveAccount(HttpRequestMessage request)
{

}
```

This will allow you to rule out a problem with the Action selection/ model binding.  If it still does not match then I suggest you turn on the trace writer and find out why it is failing to find the controller. http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing/

If it does match the above signature then take a look at this blog post http://www.bizcoder.com/?p=259 for further suggestions on how to debug serialization issues.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Darrel. I reimplemented one of the controller actions (a GET one) to use raw HttpResponseMessage and HttpRequstMessage, and, again, this works perfectly when running locally, albeit with a lot more code, but bombs horribly when I push it up to the server...

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently, and found it was caused by the incorrect order of the registrations in my Global.asax.cs.

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //XXX This order didn't work !!! XXX
  MembershipBusinessRules.CreateStandardMembershipAccounts();
  GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(...
  RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
  BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
  GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
  AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
}

void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //NOTE: Correct order of following func calls are vital !!!
  //(moved GlobalConfig(WebApiConfig.Reg) up before routes)
  MembershipBusinessRules.CreateStandardMembershipAccounts();
  GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(...
  GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
  RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
  BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
  AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
}
```