# OkHttp with basic token authentication works for GET but not for DELETE

Tags: java, android, rest, nginx, okhttp

I'm having a problem with on Android connecting to a REST service with basic jwt authentication. I'm using OkHttp 3 and Retrofit 2 for my Android code. The server is a node.js Hapi server running on AWS elasticbeanstalk with the default nginx proxy configuration. All the backend is doing is checking the authentication token for each call.

*Problem*: Both my GET and DELETE require the "Authorization" header with the token. When I call GET with the token, it works. When I do DELETE with the token, I get a 403 ACCESS DENIED, but only when the android device is connected to a cellular network and has a ipv6 address. When it's connected to my home Wi-fi, it works normally.

For some additional information, connecting directly to the nodejs server on port 8080 also makes everything work fine. I'd like to keep nginx in the picture in case I want to run multiple copies of the node server on the same box. Also, I'm very new to this and am happy to consider any alternatives.

Here is the Android code:

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(
                    new Interceptor() {
                        @Override
                        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                            Request original = chain.request();

                            //auth token for every request
                            Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                                    .addHeader("Authorization", authToken);
                            Request request = requestBuilder.build();

                            // it correctly prints out header with the token for both GET and DELETE
                            Log.d("ApiManager", "HEADERS: " + request.headers().toString()); 

                            okhttp3.Response response = chain.proceed(request);
                            return response;
                        }
                    }).build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(okClient)
            .baseUrl(MyApi.baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    myApi = retrofit.create(MyApi.class);
```

And my Nginx setup:

```
upstream nodejs {
  server 127.0.0.1:8081;
  keepalive 256;
}

server {
  listen 8080;

  if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
      set $year $1;
      set $month $2;
      set $day $3;
      set $hour $4;
  }
  access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

  location / {
      proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
      proxy_set_header   Connection "";
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  gzip on;
  gzip_comp_level 4;
  gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

}
```

**UPDATE**: It seems to work if I connect my Android device to a Wi-Fi network, but doesn't work if I'm connected to my cellular network. I'm stuck.
From the nginx access logs on the server. It does NOT log the 403 error:

1. Android device is connected to cellular network: IP: 
   "2001:56a:6ffc:d07e:0:47:2e8a:4101, 142.59.70.25" GET and POST requests work, but DELETE doesn't.
2. Android device is connected to wifi: IP: "96.51.151.36", GET, POST and DELETE work.

Comment: Not sure what is wrong with your current code, but I usually use the `@Headers` annotation in my Retrofit interface to define headers. See [their docs](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-add-custom-request-header) for more info.

Comment: It is possible your cellular data network blocks PUT and DELETE requests. If this is the case, using https will hide the headers from the firewalls and your requests will go through.

Comment: related [RESTful PUT and DELETE and firewalls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828790/restful-put-and-delete-and-firewalls)

Comment: @BenitoBertoli Thanks for the suggestion. I enabled HTTPS so that my headers won't be sniped by firewalls, but the problem persists. The problem is only when I connect to my nginx listener port (80). Port 8081 of the nodejs server works normally. So it must have something to do with my proxy settings, I'm guessing.

Answer (score 1):

If POST works and DELETE doesn't then try using HTTP method overriding with either the `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header or the `_method` query parameter and see if it works that way.

If it starts working then you'll know it's a problem on the HTTP level (like a problem with some proxy). If it doesn't then you'll know that it's a problem with your route handlers.

See [Common non-standard request fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Common_non-standard_request_fields) on Wikipedia. Whether or not you want to use it in the long run is another question but it will let you narrow the problem quickly.

You didn't post any backend code and you didn't even say what framework is used on the backend so no specific answer can be provided on how to do that. If you're using Express then you can use the  [method-override](https://www.npmjs.com/package/method-override) middleware.

Also in one of the other questions that you posted about the same problem you showed your nginx configuration and it seems that what you're doing is basically proxying the traffic from port 8080 to 8081 for some reason. Try connecting directly to 8081 to rule out the possibility that it is your own proxy that is causing the problem.

(By the way, it would be easier if you posted all of the relevant info in one question instead of scattering it between 3 or 4 similar questions about the same problem. Questions can be edited to add more info after they are posted. See: [How do edits work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789/157646) for more info.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I deleted all the duplicate questions. The 8080 to 8081 proxy setup is just the default AWS elastic beanstalk configuration for nginx. I tried connecting directly to 8080 and the problem goes away. In the nginx access logs, the ipv6 address is no longer logged for the device on the mobile network ("-" instead).